# How to find the 4th degree polynomial with given values at $0,1,2,3,4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, interpolation

Determine a fourth degree polynomial p that has $p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4)$ equal to $7, 1, 3, 1, 7$, respectively. Using my ideas, I first write out the points on the polynomial as $(0,7), (1, 1),(2, 3), (4, 7).$ I assume a four degree polynomial will have the general formula $$p(x) = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$$ Since at $x=0$, $p(0) = 7$, it follows that $ e=7.$

My problem now is to find a, b, c, and d.

Comment: Couldn't you use the other 4 points to create 4 equations with 4 unknowns and then use basic row reduction to figure out a,b,c, and d?

Comment: ^^ Well, 5 points

Comment: Check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: Folks: the title indicates this is a precalculus problem. The OP has not yet encountered row reduction, nor is in the position to learn Lagrange Polynomials. Please try to meet the OP where he/she is at?

Comment: Unless you've learned other techniques, the easiest method (and it's not *that* easy) is to set $e=7$ as you've noted, then use the remaining four points to construct four equations in four unknowns and then solve them (perhaps by eliminating variables).

Comment: You don't need any Calculus course to understand what's going on with Lagrange interpolation. I learnt it in high school as a matter of fact.

Comment: Depending on the sequences learned prior to pre-calculus, it is entirely possible that a pre-calc student would indeed have learned row reduction.  (I am currently TA'ing for a course targeted at students who wont go down the calculus track where our current unit has gaussian elimination)

Comment: $x^4-8x^3+21x^2-20x+7$

Answer (score 5):

**Symmetry** is our friend, let's exploit it (that didn't come out sounding quite right.)

There is obvious symmetry about $x=2$. Symmetry about $0$ is nicer, so we first find a polynomial $q(x)$ such that $q(0)=3$, $q(\pm 1)=1$ and $q(\pm 2)=7$. Let's look for such a polynomial of shape $$q(x)=3+ax^2(x^2-1)+bx^2(x^2-4).$$

Plug in $x=2$ to find $a$ and $x=1$ to find $b$.

Then **shift** $q(x)$ suitably: $p(x)=q(x-2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Lets solve an easier case: $q(x)$ a 2nd degree polynomial and $q(1) = 1$, $q(4) = 3$ and $q(5) = 2$. It's easy to check that the following polynomial expression has the degree we want and when evaluated at 0, 4 and 5 it gives the values we expect:

$$
Q(x) = 1\cdot\frac{(x-4)(x-5)}{(1-4)(1-5)} + 3\cdot\frac{(x-5)(x-1)}{(4-5)(4-1)} + 2\cdot\frac{(x-1)(x-4)}{(5-1)(5-4)} 
$$

Therefore it must be the polynomial we are looking for, $Q(x) = q(x)$ (though, of course, you have to expand the expression to get the coefficients). Try to understand what is the trick used and then adapt it to your 4th degree polynomial.

Comment: I think you mean q(1)=1.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in the known values and you would get $4$ (linear) equations with $4$ variables.

This is a bit much - but is doable.

If you are advanced and know what are matrices then you can use it to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another method, using the fact that the inputs are consecutive integers starting with zero. It’s the method of finite differences, in which you make repeated use of the operator $\Delta$, where $(\Delta f)(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$. The basic polynomials here are $C_0(x)=1$ (constant), $C_1(x)=x$, $C_2(x)=x(x-1)/2!$, $C_3(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)/3!$, etc. In our example, I write down the original function values on the top row, and the values of $\Delta^nf$ in the succeeding rows:
\begin{align}
7\quad 1\quad3\quad1\quad7\\
-6\quad2-2\quad6\quad\>\\
8\quad-4\quad8\quad\quad\\
-12\quad12\quad\quad\quad\quad\\
24\qquad\quad\quad\quad\quad
\end{align}
Then the desired polynomial is gotten by reading down the left column: $f(x)=7C_0-6C_1+8C_2-12C_3+24C_4$.

If you are not averse to teaching a *method* without a supporting explanation, this is perfectly well suited to willing elementary school students.

Answer (score -1):

a+uh=x
0+u=x
u=x

7   -6   8   -12   24
1    2  -4    12
3   -2   8
1    6
7

y=7+u(-6)+u(u-1)/2 *8 +u(u-1)(u-2)/6 *-12 +u(u-1)(u-2)(u-3)/24 *(24)

replace u by x

y=7-6x+4(x)(x-1)-2(x)(x-1)(x-2)+(x)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).